# Bash display the ordinary files which have been modified

Tags: bash

I am not sure what the correct command is to display all the modified files in the current session? This is what I thought, but I receive errors.

```
alias display="ls -t | head -n *"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but the interpretation I glean is that you want a way to identify what files have been created or modified in your current user session (i.e. 'since you logged on'). The question itself is somewhat involved, but the first thing you need to do is establish when you logged on.

The `last` command will read `/var/log/wtmp` to obtain that information for you. The key is to use the `still logged on` field, and to get the date in a format that will be useful to determine what files have changed since logon. One approach is:

```
date -d "$(last $USER | grep still | head -n1 | cut -c 40-55)" "+%Y%m%d%H%M"
```

Capture that information for use in a variable in the format useful to the `touch` command:

```
logontm=$(date -d "$(last $USER | grep still | head -n1 | cut -c 40-55)" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

With the date/time of logon, and with the date in the current format, you can pass that date to `touch` to create a temporary file with the create/mod time of last logon:

```
touch -t $logontm /tmp/tmp.$logontm
```

With a file with the create/mod time of last logon, you can then use the `find` command to find all files that have been created or changed since you logged on:

```
find /path/to/check -newer /tmp/tmp.$logontm
```

You can tailor `/path/to/check` to the relevant areas of the filesystem that you are interested in. You can also tailor the `find` command to limit the type of files selected. (e.g. adding `-type f` for regular files) For all files under your home directory, you can substitute `$HOME` for the `/path/to/check`. Save the results or use them however you need. Then simply removed the tmp file:

```
rm /tmp/tmp.$logontm
```

Now granted, there are probably other ways to approach this, and you can put all of this together in a single command, but off-hand, I can't think of another way to get all new/changed files for a session. If you want to combine all in one command, it would be similar to the following to check your `home` directory for new and changed files for the session (shown with `line continuations` for readability):

```
logontm=$(date -d "$(last $USER | grep still | head -n1 | cut -c 40-55)" "+%Y%m%d%H%M") && \
touch -t $logontm /tmp/tmp.$logontm && \
find $HOME -newer /tmp/tmp.$logontm && \
rm /tmp/tmp.$logontm
```

**Note:** depending on the version/implementation of `last` on you system, you may need to adjust the `cut` command to insure you are collecting the proper logon date/time.

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n *
```

Appends a list of all files in the local directory to the `head -n` command, so it will look something like this:

```
head -n a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

But `-n` requires a number, namely the number of lines to print. So when it gets an `a.txt`, it fails. If you want to print the youngest, say 10, files, the command you want is this:

```
ls -t | head -n 10 --
```

If you want to have the first 10 lines of each file in order of their creation date, you need this:

```
for f in $(ls -t); do head -n 10 $f; done
```

If you want something else, you need to let us know.